# Delimiter Issue

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am using a Mac laptop and I am trying to copy a local csv file and import it into a postgresql table. I have used the delimiter query and the following query works:

```
copy c2013_levinj.va_clips_translation 
from local '/Users/jacoblevin/Desktop/clips_translation_table.csv' 
Delimiter ',' skip 1 rejectmax 1;
```

However, each time the query is submitted, I receive a message that says "0 rows fetched." I have tried dropping the table and re-creating it as well as using the "select *" query. Suffice to say, i have been unable to pull any data. Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this:

```
copy c2013_levinj.va_clips_translation 
from local '/Users/jacoblevin/Desktop/clips_translation_table.csv' 
WITH CSV HEADER;
```

That should be more robust and do what you want.